# Pass variables to XMLHttpRequest - collect in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have this XMLHttpRequest that I'm passing to PHP using POST. 
Now, I want to pass an additional parameter as well, but XMLHttpRequest is constructed a different way that regular AJAX. So I'm not sure how I can pass multiple variables and collect them separatly in PHP?

The code looks like this:

```
    xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
    xhr.send(file);
```

I want to pass this as well:

```
    var dynurl = $("#dynname").text();
    var dynurl = "dynFolder="+dynurl;
```

So that I can get it in PHP like this (if possible):

```
$dynFolder = ($_POST['dynFolder']);
```

What do I do to pass more more than the one variable?
Btw: I'm using this as a strarting point:
http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/

Comment: I doubt this file upload works.

Comment: I didn't think you could upload a file with an XHR without doing some type of hack, like `jquery.form.js` does. Maybe the newer XHR model allows for it?

Comment: This is just a fragment of the code. Didn't bother posting it all, because this is only thing I'm having trouble with right now.